# Доступ к сайту dropbox.com

Tags: веб-сайт

Проблема: при попытке зайти на dropbox.com возникает ошибка "err_connection_refused'. С телефона всё работает отлично. Изменил DNS, очистил кеш и историю запросов, перезагрузил ПК, отключил VPN и другие разширения для браузера, интернет стабильный, другие сайты открываются. Уже 2 часа бьюсь над проблемой, подскажите что можно сделать.

Comment: вам скорее всего — в роскомнадзор.

Comment: Для начала выяснить к какому ip пытается подключится браузер и правда ли это ip дропбокса

Comment: Всё проверил, сайт не подделка

Comment: Насчёт Роскомнадзора, я с Украины